# NAs introduced by coercion ( No missing values)

Tags: r

I have tweets with coordinates. I want to pin them on map according to locations.When I try to run this code block, its giving a  "NAs introduced by coercion" error.I think there is a problem with seperator or as.numeric function.The problem may be caused by this I read all other topics but I didnt figure it out the solution.

```
    library(dplyr)
    library(tidyr)


    options(stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

    json_file <- "db1.json"

    boulder_flood_tweets <- stream_in(file(json_file))

    tweet_data <- data.frame(date_time = boulder_flood_tweets$created_at,
                     username = boulder_flood_tweets$user$screen_name,
                     tweet_text = boulder_flood_tweets$text,
                     coords = boulder_flood_tweets$coordinates)

    start_date <- as.POSIXct('2013-09-13 00:00:00')
    end_date <- as.POSIXct('2019-05-12 00:00:00')

    flood_tweets <- tweet_data %>%
     mutate(coords.coordinates = gsub("\\)|c\\(", "", coords.coordinates),
     date_time = as.POSIXct(date_time, format = "%a %b %d %H:%M:%S +0000 %Y")) %>%
     separate(coords.coordinates, c("long", "lat"), sep = ", ") %>%
     mutate_at(c("lat", "long"), as.numeric) %>%
     filter(date_time >= start_date & date_time <= end_date )
```

Image of coordinates sample: https://ibb.co/NV5PKzQ

Image of my dataset: https://ibb.co/0K68sc5

Comment: The way you debug this is to (1) run your code up to the `mutate_at`, (2) use `which` and `is.na` to find (some of) the values that ended up as NAs, (3) Go back & examine the original values in those cells to identify what about them is different that you haven't accounted for

Comment: Can you can give a sample of your data using `dput(tweet_data)` ? Thanks.

Comment: 1:2), 
    structure(list(`$numberDouble` = c("-47.2356987", "-22.7734795"
    )), class = "data.frame", row.names = 1:2))), row.names = c(1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 
16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 29L, 
,....4051L),class="data.frame")